# Dyna-Q with planning vs. n-step Q-learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm reading Reinforcement Learning by Sutton and Barto, and for an example of Dyna-Q, they use a maze problem.  The example shows that with n=50 steps of planning, the algorithm reaches the optimal path in only 3 episodes.

Is this an improvement over 50-step Q-learning?  It seems like you are really just running a bunch of 50-step Q-learning algorithms in each episode, so saying it finds the optimal path in 3 episodes is misleading.

Also, I guess the big question is, I thought Dyna-Q was useful when you don't have a model of the environment, but in this example don't we have a model of the environment?  Why use all of the memory to save all our previous moves if we already have a model?  I'm having trouble understanding why this is a good example for Dyna-Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, we don't have the model. We have it in practice just for simulation, but in real life we don't.

Dyna-Q basically approximate your model using sample. Instead of learning the transition and the reward functions, you "query" your data: what happened in the past when I did action `a` in state `s`? If everything is deterministic, this is equivalent of knowing the exact model.

Think it also like this. In classic Q-learning your know only your current `s,a`, so you update `Q(s,a)` only when you visit it. In Dyna-Q, you update all `Q(s,a)` every time you 
query them from the memory. You don't have to revisit them. This speeds up things tremendously.

Also, the very common "replay memory" basically reinvented Dyna-Q, even though nobody acknowledges it.